# How to access "Contacts found in mail" that are not in the address book

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to be able to display the contacts listed in "Contacts found in mail" similar to Mail.app, or the way the phone displays "Maybe: {Contact Name}".  I would like access to the scrapped contacts when an email address or phone number is in an email but not saved in the device Contacts db.

Is this currently a private API? I am unable to find any documentation around this functionality.

Comment: The email address is probably coming from the email header. The phone number and other information is probably coming from a `NSDataDetector`. See: http://nshipster.com/nsdatadetector/ or https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdatadetector

Comment: @RoboticCat - The emails listed in Mail.app (and Calendar.app) are scrapped from your mail conversations.  Phone.app shows a suggestion for an unknown number if that number was previously in an email.  You are correct, it is coming from a `NSDataDetector` -  don't wan't to detect the phone number, I want to be able to search the DB of scrapped contact info.